# DATEDIFF with variable seed

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql, datediff

I have the following table

[image]

The first column are transaction dates order by Date DESC. 
The second column is binary state for each transaction, could be either 0 or 1. 
The third column is the datediff of the minimum date compared to each date. 
the code that produces this table is something like that

```
DECLARE @date DATE 
SELECT @Date = MIN(CONVERT(DATE,Transaction_Created)) FROM #dates
SELECT      CONVERT(DATE,Transaction_Created)                       AS Date
    ,       MAX(Is_Deposit)                                         AS Is_Deposit
    ,       DATEDIFF(dd,@Date,CONVERT(DATE,Transaction_Created))    AS Datedif  

FROM        #DATES
GROUP BY    CONVERT(DATE,Transaction_Created)
order by 1 desc
```

My problem is that when is_Deposit=1 i need to reset my seed for DATEDIFF and the date of IS_Deposit =1 become my new MIN Date and so on for each IS_Deposit=1 i find in the table.
For example from 2015-12-04 until 2015-12-16 everything is ok. But in line 746 2015-12-17 i would like this to be 1 again and not 13 as we have reached the next IS_Deposit=1 and we have to reset.

Resultset now:

```
Date    Is_Deposit  Datedif

2016-02-12  0   70
2016-02-11  0   69
2016-02-10  0   68
2016-02-09  0   67
2016-02-08  0   66
2016-02-07  0   65
2016-02-06  0   64
2016-02-05  0   63
2016-02-04  0   62
2016-02-03  0   61
2016-02-02  0   60
2016-02-01  0   59
2016-01-31  0   58
2016-01-30  0   57
2016-01-29  0   56
2016-01-28  0   55
2016-01-27  0   54
2016-01-26  0   53
2016-01-25  0   52
2016-01-24  0   51
2016-01-23  0   50
2016-01-22  0   49
2016-01-21  0   48
2016-01-20  1   47
2016-01-17  0   44
2016-01-16  0   43
2016-01-15  0   42
2016-01-14  0   41
2016-01-13  0   40
2016-01-12  0   39
2016-01-11  0   38
2016-01-10  0   37
2016-01-09  0   36
2016-01-08  0   35
2016-01-07  0   34
2016-01-06  0   33
2016-01-05  0   32
2016-01-04  0   31
2016-01-03  0   30
2016-01-02  0   29
2016-01-01  0   28
2015-12-31  0   27
2015-12-30  0   26
2015-12-29  0   25
2015-12-28  0   24
2015-12-27  0   23
2015-12-26  0   22
2015-12-25  1   21
2015-12-20  0   16
2015-12-19  0   15
2015-12-18  0   14
2015-12-17  0   13
2015-12-16  1   12
2015-12-14  0   10
2015-12-13  0   9
2015-12-12  0   8
2015-12-11  0   7
2015-12-10  0   6
2015-12-09  0   5
2015-12-08  0   4
2015-12-07  0   3
2015-12-05  0   1
2015-12-04  1   0
```

Resultset Required:

```
2016-02-12  0   23

2016-02-11  0   22
2016-02-10  0   21
2016-02-09  0   20
2016-02-08  0   19
2016-02-07  0   18
2016-02-06  0   17
2016-02-05  0   16
2016-02-04  0   15
2016-02-03  0   14
2016-02-02  0   13
2016-02-01  0   12
2016-01-31  0   11
2016-01-30  0   10
2016-01-29  0   9
2016-01-28  0   8
2016-01-27  0   7
2016-01-26  0   6
2016-01-25  0   5
2016-01-24  0   4
2016-01-23  0   3
2016-01-22  0   2
2016-01-21  0   1
2016-01-20  1   26
2016-01-17  0   23
2016-01-16  0   22
2016-01-15  0   21
2016-01-14  0   20
2016-01-13  0   19
2016-01-12  0   18
2016-01-11  0   17
2016-01-10  0   16
2016-01-09  0   15
2016-01-08  0   14
2016-01-07  0   13
2016-01-06  0   12
2016-01-05  0   11
2016-01-04  0   10
2016-01-03  0   9
2016-01-02  0   8
2016-01-01  0   7
2015-12-31  0   6
2015-12-30  0   5
2015-12-29  0   4
2015-12-28  0   3
2015-12-27  0   2
2015-12-26  0   1
2015-12-25  1   9
2015-12-20  0   4
2015-12-19  0   3
2015-12-18  0   2
2015-12-17  0   1
2015-12-16  1   12
2015-12-14  0   10
2015-12-13  0   9
2015-12-12  0   8
2015-12-11  0   7
2015-12-10  0   6
2015-12-09  0   5
2015-12-08  0   4
2015-12-07  0   3
2015-12-05  0   1
2015-12-04  1   0
```

Comment: Please don't provide images of tables. If you are going to provide data, do so as tabular formatted `text`, or (even better) and DDL and DML statements. Then we can consume your data and test against it. What are your expected results for your dataset here? Also, you should really avoid ordering by ordinal position: [Bad habits to kick : ORDER BY ordinal](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/06/bad-habits-to-kick-order-by-ordinal)

Comment: You're welcome. Please do update your question with some of the point (consumable sample data and expected results are very important for us to be able to help you easily). Many users will ignore a post with images of data, as the image isn't useful to them to try and help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with a couple of window functions. First a running total to build a cumulative sequence ID then pick out the minimum within each sequence:

```
With 
DatesSequence AS
(
SELECT Date,Is_Deposit
, SUM(Is_Deposit) OVER(ORDER BY Date DESC) AS Sequence
FROM #Dates
)
SELECT 
Date
,Is_Deposit
, DATEDIFF(day,
            MIN(Date) OVER (PARTITION BY Sequence),
            Date) + 1 AS DateDif
FROM DatesSequence
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple subquery can solve this problem.
First, create and populate sample table (**Please** save us this step in your future questions):

```
DECLARE @T AS TABLE
(
    Date date,
    Is_Deposit bit,
    Datedif int
);

INSERT INTO @T (Date, Is_Deposit, Datedif) VALUES
('2016-02-12', 0, 70),
('2016-02-11', 0, 69),
('2016-02-10', 0, 68),
('2016-02-09', 0, 67),
('2016-02-08', 0, 66),
('2016-02-07', 0, 65),
('2016-02-06', 0, 64),
('2016-02-05', 0, 63),
('2016-02-04', 0, 62),
('2016-02-03', 0, 61),
('2016-02-02', 0, 60),
('2016-02-01', 0, 59),
('2016-01-31', 0, 58),
('2016-01-30', 0, 57),
('2016-01-29', 0, 56),
('2016-01-28', 0, 55),
('2016-01-27', 0, 54),
('2016-01-26', 0, 53),
('2016-01-25', 0, 52),
('2016-01-24', 0, 51),
('2016-01-23', 0, 50),
('2016-01-22', 0, 49),
('2016-01-21', 0, 48),
('2016-01-20', 1, 47),
('2016-01-17', 0, 44),
('2016-01-16', 0, 43),
('2016-01-15', 0, 42),
('2016-01-14', 0, 41),
('2016-01-13', 0, 40),
('2016-01-12', 0, 39),
('2016-01-11', 0, 38),
('2016-01-10', 0, 37),
('2016-01-09', 0, 36),
('2016-01-08', 0, 35),
('2016-01-07', 0, 34),
('2016-01-06', 0, 33),
('2016-01-05', 0, 32),
('2016-01-04', 0, 31),
('2016-01-03', 0, 30),
('2016-01-02', 0, 29),
('2016-01-01', 0, 28),
('2015-12-31', 0, 27),
('2015-12-30', 0, 26),
('2015-12-29', 0, 25),
('2015-12-28', 0, 24),
('2015-12-27', 0, 23),
('2015-12-26', 0, 22),
('2015-12-25', 1, 21),
('2015-12-20', 0, 16),
('2015-12-19', 0, 15),
('2015-12-18', 0, 14),
('2015-12-17', 0, 13),
('2015-12-16', 1, 12),
('2015-12-14', 0, 10),
('2015-12-13', 0, 9 ),
('2015-12-12', 0, 8 ),
('2015-12-11', 0, 7 ),
('2015-12-10', 0, 6 ),
('2015-12-09', 0, 5 ),
('2015-12-08', 0, 4 ),
('2015-12-07', 0, 3 ),
('2015-12-05', 0, 1 ),
('2015-12-04', 1, 0 );
```

The query:

```
SELECT    Date
        , Is_Deposit
        , DATEDIFF(
            DAY, 
            (
                SELECT TOP 1 Date 
                FROM @T AS t1 
                WHERE t1.Date <= t0.Date 
                AND Is_Deposit = 1
            ), 
            Date
        ) As Datedif
FROM @T As t0
```

Results:

```
Date        Is_Deposit  Datedif
2016-02-12  0           23
2016-02-11  0           22
2016-02-10  0           21
2016-02-09  0           20
2016-02-08  0           19
2016-02-07  0           18
2016-02-06  0           17
2016-02-05  0           16
2016-02-04  0           15
2016-02-03  0           14
2016-02-02  0           13
2016-02-01  0           12
2016-01-31  0           11
2016-01-30  0           10
2016-01-29  0           9
2016-01-28  0           8
2016-01-27  0           7
2016-01-26  0           6
2016-01-25  0           5
2016-01-24  0           4
2016-01-23  0           3
2016-01-22  0           2
2016-01-21  0           1
2016-01-20  1           0
2016-01-17  0           23
2016-01-16  0           22
2016-01-15  0           21
2016-01-14  0           20
2016-01-13  0           19
2016-01-12  0           18
2016-01-11  0           17
2016-01-10  0           16
2016-01-09  0           15
2016-01-08  0           14
2016-01-07  0           13
2016-01-06  0           12
2016-01-05  0           11
2016-01-04  0           10
2016-01-03  0           9
2016-01-02  0           8
2016-01-01  0           7
2015-12-31  0           6
2015-12-30  0           5
2015-12-29  0           4
2015-12-28  0           3
2015-12-27  0           2
2015-12-26  0           1
2015-12-25  1           0
2015-12-20  0           4
2015-12-19  0           3
2015-12-18  0           2
2015-12-17  0           1
2015-12-16  1           0
2015-12-14  0           10
2015-12-13  0           9
2015-12-12  0           8
2015-12-11  0           7
2015-12-10  0           6
2015-12-09  0           5
2015-12-08  0           4
2015-12-07  0           3
2015-12-05  0           1
2015-12-04  1           0
```

If you want to update the table, you can change the query into a cte and update like this:

```
WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT    Date
            , Is_Deposit
            , Datedif
            , DATEDIFF(
                DAY, 
                (
                    SELECT TOP 1 Date 
                    FROM @T AS t1 
                    WHERE t1.Date <= t0.Date 
                    AND Is_Deposit = 1
                ), 
                Date
            ) As NewDatedif
    FROM @T As t0
)

UPDATE CTE 
SET dateDif = NewDateDif;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can just use a cumulative conditional `max()`.  I cannot tell if aggregation is actually needed, so this might do what you want:

```
SELECT Date, Is_Deposit,
       COALESCE(DATEDIFF(day,
                         date,
                         MAX(CASE WHEN Is_Deposit = 1 THEN DATE END) OVER
                             (ORDER BY Date
                              ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW
                             )
                        ), 0
               )
FROM #Dates
```